# Angularjs init checked status and ngModel value

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm using angularjs 1.6.1

This is my HTML:

```
<label ng-if="parents.children" ng-repeat="child in parents.children" class="checkbox" >
    <input type="checkbox"
            ng-model="selected.category[parents.cat_ID][child.cat_ID]"
            id="{{child.cat_ID}}"
            name="{{child.cat_ID}}"
    >
    <i class="icon fa fa-circle-o"></i>
    <span class="name">{{child.name}} {{child.found}} {{child.cat_ID}}</span>
</label>
```

I need to do 2 things:

1) to show the checkboxes checked IF {{child.found}} is true.

2) AND also to init the values found inside **$scope.selected = {}** (the ngModels)

My issue is that if I add to input:

```
ng-checked="child.found"
```

Then the checkboxes will be checked alright, but the $scope.selected will be completely empty. If I use instead:

```
ng-init="selected.category[parents.cat_ID][child.cat_ID] = child.found"
```

Then it will fill $scope.selected with the correct values, but shows the checkboxes checked status completely wrong [image: checkbox status wrong]

I have even tried

```
ng-false-value="false"
ng-true-value="true"
```

But nothing changed...

Appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

that's because `ngInit` directive doesn't create a new scope and populate the variable in your current scope.

in the other case instead , if you assign `selected` inside the `ng-if` block you are doing it inside `ngIf` child scope that is different from your controller scope (it's  prototype inherited from the parent scope, but every change to its scope will "mask" the outer scope) ,that's why you see `$scope.selected` still empty.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification... but this means I can't achieve what I would like? To show both the checked data and have them in the selected?

Comment: yes using ng-init, or you can try changing ng-if with ng-show

Comment: Well, I've removed ng-if completely (tried it with ng-show as well) but got same results... any other alternative? I've been on this for hours... starting to think of a manual ugly workaround, which I don't really like...